# Can't scroll to the bottom of an iScroll div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

So I'm trying to use the [iScroll demo here](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/issues/378) - the Zhuinden post.

And so I've got this code in my app (which will be a PhoneGap mobile app) - scrolling works fine on my laptop/desktop, but for some reason I can't scroll to the bottom of the div on mobile (in a mobile app).

Here's the code:

```
<script>

function pullDownAction(theScroller) {
    var el, li, i;  
    //TODO: do your things
    theScroller.refresh(); //just in case
}
function pullUpAction(theScroller) {
    var el, li, i;
    //TODO: doYourThings();
    theScroller.refresh(); //just in case
}


var IScrollPullUpDown = function(wrapperName, iScrollConfig, pullDownActionHandler, pullUpActionHandler) {
    var iScrollConfig, pullDownActionHandler, pullUpActionHandler, pullDownEl, pullDownOffset, pullUpEl, scrollStartPos;
    var pullThreshold = 5;
    var me = this;

    function showPullDownElNow(className) {
        // Shows pullDownEl with a given className
        pullDownEl.style.transitionDuration = '';
        pullDownEl.style.marginTop = '';
        pullDownEl.className = 'pullDown ' + className;
    }

    var hidePullDownEl = function(time, refresh) {
        // Hides pullDownEl
        pullDownEl.style.transitionDuration = (time > 0 ? time + 'ms' : '');
        pullDownEl.style.marginTop = '';
        pullDownEl.className = 'pullDown scrolledUp';

        // If refresh==true, refresh again after time+10 ms to update iScroll's "scroller.offsetHeight" after the pull-down-bar is really hidden...
        // Don't refresh when the user is still dragging, as this will cause the content to jump (i.e. don't refresh while dragging)
        if(refresh) setTimeout(function() {
            me.myScroll.refresh();
        }, time + 10);
    }

    function init() {
        var wrapperObj = document.querySelector('#' + wrapperName);
        var scrollerObj = wrapperObj.children[0];

        if(pullDownActionHandler) {
            // If a pullDownActionHandler-function is supplied, add a pull-down bar at the top and enable pull-down-to-refresh.
            // (if pullDownActionHandler==null this iScroll will have no pull-down-functionality)
            pullDownEl = document.createElement('div');
            pullDownEl.className = 'pullDown scrolledUp';
            pullDownEl.innerHTML = '<span class="pullDownIcon"></span><span class="pullDownLabel">Pull down to refresh...</span>';
            scrollerObj.insertBefore(pullDownEl, scrollerObj.firstChild);
            pullDownOffset = pullDownEl.offsetHeight;
        }
        if(pullUpActionHandler) {
            // If a pullUpActionHandler-function is supplied, add a pull-up bar in the bottom and enable pull-up-to-load.
            // (if pullUpActionHandler==null this iScroll will have no pull-up-functionality)
            pullUpEl = document.createElement('div');
            pullUpEl.className = 'pullUp';
            pullUpEl.innerHTML = '<span class="pullUpIcon"></span><span class="pullUpLabel">Pull up to load more...</span>';
            //scrollerObj.appendChild(pullUpEl);
        }

        me.myScroll = new IScroll(wrapperObj, iScrollConfig);

        me.myScroll.on('refresh', function() {
            if((pullDownEl) && (pullDownEl.className.match('loading'))) {
                pullDownEl.querySelector('.pullDownLabel').innerHTML = 'Pull down to refresh...';
                if(this.y >= 0) {
                    // The pull-down-bar is fully visible:
                    // Hide it with a simple 250ms animation
                    hidePullDownEl(250, true);
                } else if(this.y > -pullDownOffset) {
                    // The pull-down-bar is PARTLY visible:
                    pullDownEl.style.marginTop = this.y + 'px';

                    // CSS-trick to force webkit to render/update any CSS-changes immediately: Access the offsetHeight property...
                    pullDownEl.offsetHeight;

                    var animTime = (250 * (pullDownOffset + this.y) / pullDownOffset);
                    this.scrollTo(0, 0, 0);   
                    setTimeout(function() { 
                        hidePullDownEl(animTime, true);
                    }, 0);

                } else {
                    hidePullDownEl(0, true);
                    this.scrollBy(0, pullDownOffset, 0);
                }
            }
            if((pullUpEl) && (pullUpEl.className.match('loading'))) {
                pullUpEl.className = 'pullUp';
                pullUpEl.querySelector('.pullUpLabel').innerHTML = 'Pull up to load more...';
            }
        });

        me.myScroll.on('scrollStart', function() {
            scrollStartPos = this.y; // Store the scroll starting point to be able to track movement in 'scroll' below
        });

        me.myScroll.on('scroll', function() {
            if(pullDownEl || pullUpEl) {
                if((scrollStartPos == 0) && (this.y == 0)) {
                    this.hasVerticalScroll = true;

                    // Set scrollStartPos to -1000 to be able to detect this state later...
                    scrollStartPos = -1000;
                } else if((scrollStartPos == -1000) &&
                    (((!pullUpEl) && (!pullDownEl.className.match('flip')) && (this.y < 0)) ||
                    ((!pullDownEl) && (!pullUpEl.className.match('flip')) && (this.y > 0)))) {
                    this.hasVerticalScroll = false;
                    scrollStartPos = 0;
                    this.scrollBy(0, -this.y, 0);   // Adjust scrolling position to undo this "invalid" movement
                }
            }

            if(pullDownEl) {
                if(this.y > pullDownOffset + pullThreshold && !pullDownEl.className.match('flip')) {
                    showPullDownElNow('flip');
                    this.scrollBy(0, -pullDownOffset, 0);   // Adjust scrolling position to match the change in pullDownEl's margin-top
                    pullDownEl.querySelector('.pullDownLabel').innerHTML = 'Release to refresh...';
                } else if(this.y < 0 && pullDownEl.className.match('flip')) { // User changes his mind...
                    hidePullDownEl(0, false);
                    this.scrollBy(0, pullDownOffset, 0);    // Adjust scrolling position to match the change in pullDownEl's margin-top
                    pullDownEl.querySelector('.pullDownLabel').innerHTML = 'Pull down to refresh...';
                }
            }
            if(pullUpEl) {
                if(this.y < (this.maxScrollY - pullThreshold) && !pullUpEl.className.match('flip')) {
                    pullUpEl.className = 'pullUp flip';
                    pullUpEl.querySelector('.pullUpLabel').innerHTML = 'Release to load more...';
                } else if(this.y > (this.maxScrollY + pullThreshold) && pullUpEl.className.match('flip')) {
                    pullUpEl.className = 'pullUp';
                    pullUpEl.querySelector('.pullUpLabel').innerHTML = 'Pull up to load more...';
                }
            }
        });

        me.myScroll.on('scrollEnd', function() {
            if((pullDownEl) && (pullDownEl.className.match('flip'))) {
                showPullDownElNow('loading');
                pullDownEl.querySelector('.pullDownLabel').innerHTML = 'Loading...';
                pullDownActionHandler(this);    // Execute custom function (ajax call?)
            }
            if((pullUpEl) && (pullUpEl.className.match('flip'))) {
                pullUpEl.className = 'pullUp loading';
                pullUpEl.querySelector('.pullUpLabel').innerHTML = 'Loading...';
                pullUpActionHandler(this);  // Execute custom function (ajax call?)
            }
            if(scrollStartPos == -1000) {
                this.hasVerticalScroll = this.options.scrollY && this.maxScrollY < 0;
            }
        });

        me.myScroll.refresh();
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        init();
    }, false);
};


var scroller1 = new IScrollPullUpDown('messages-wrapper', {
    probeType: 2,
    bounceTime: 250,
    bounceEasing: 'quadratic',
    mouseWheel: false,
    scrollbars: true,
    fadeScrollbars: true,
    interactiveScrollbars: false,
    click: true,
    tap: true
}, pullDownAction, pullUpAction);

function blockTouchMove(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}

document.addEventListener('touchmove', blockTouchMove, false);

</script>



<div id="messages-wrapper"><div id="messages"></div></div>
```

I'm not seeing what it could possibly be. I've tried changing scroll distance, I've tried selecting disabling part of the code. I'm just not sure what exactly is restricting me from scrolling all the way down, and it doesn't appear like anyone else is having this particular issue.

Could it be because I am updating the size of my div via AJAX (I'm adding messages)? How do I replicate iOS pull down for new message functionality with iScroll?

EDIT: Here's a JSFiddle that doesn't work. I may do changes based on certain things to it:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ymesooL/)

and JSFiddle that is closer to production **(and it is absolutely NOT working to scroll in iOS 11 here):**

[JSFiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/qr6o5deq/11/)

Comment: My first impulse is that this maybe have nothing to do with the JS itself but with some CSS, could that be? How could I test the hole thing?

Comment: I can toss it into a JSFiddle real quick

Comment: Put one in. I may make changes if I determine that there's something that's missing or configured wrong

Comment: Can you try if you add the folowing CSS line to `#scroller li` `box-sizing: border-box;` because this is what I had one

Comment: I added it, I'm not seeing it able to scroll at all currently.

Answer (score 1):

So first of all the whole code needs to be refactored, and organized. No Offence but this is a big mess.

Second:
jQuery was not properely loaded in the fiddle neither the iScroll script. After fixing them, iScroll worked very fine on both laptop, and mobile.

Test it **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/6ymesooL/6/)**

```
function pullDownAction(theScroller) {
    var el, li, i;  
    //TODO: do your things
    theScroller.refresh(); //just in case
}
function pullUpAction(theScroller) {
    var el, li, i;
    //TODO: doYourThings();
    theScroller.refresh(); //just in case
}


var IScrollPullUpDown = function(wrapperName, iScrollConfig, pullDownActionHandler, pullUpActionHandler) {
    var iScrollConfig, pullDownActionHandler, pullUpActionHandler, pullDownEl, pullDownOffset, pullUpEl, scrollStartPos;
    var pullThreshold = 5;
    var me = this;
    init();

    function showPullDownElNow(className) {
        // Shows pullDownEl with a given className
        pullDownEl.style.transitionDuration = '';
        pullDownEl.style.marginTop = '';
        pullDownEl.className = 'pullDown ' + className;
    }

    var hidePullDownEl = function(time, refresh) {
        // Hides pullDownEl
        pullDownEl.style.transitionDuration = (time > 0 ? time + 'ms' : '');
        pullDownEl.style.marginTop = '';
        pullDownEl.className = 'pullDown scrolledUp';

        // If refresh==true, refresh again after time+10 ms to update iScroll's "scroller.offsetHeight" after the pull-down-bar is really hidden...
        // Don't refresh when the user is still dragging, as this will cause the content to jump (i.e. don't refresh while dragging)
        if(refresh) setTimeout(function() {
            me.myScroll.refresh();
        }, time + 10);
    }

    function init() {

        var wrapperObj = document.querySelector('#' + wrapperName);
        var scrollerObj = wrapperObj.children[0];
        console.log(wrapperObj)

        if(pullDownActionHandler) {
            // If a pullDownActionHandler-function is supplied, add a pull-down bar at the top and enable pull-down-to-refresh.
            // (if pullDownActionHandler==null this iScroll will have no pull-down-functionality)
            pullDownEl = document.createElement('div');
            pullDownEl.className = 'pullDown scrolledUp';
            pullDownEl.innerHTML = '<span class="pullDownIcon"></span><span class="pullDownLabel">Pull down to refresh...</span>';
            scrollerObj.insertBefore(pullDownEl, scrollerObj.firstChild);
            pullDownOffset = pullDownEl.offsetHeight;
        }
        if(pullUpActionHandler) {
            // If a pullUpActionHandler-function is supplied, add a pull-up bar in the bottom and enable pull-up-to-load.
            // (if pullUpActionHandler==null this iScroll will have no pull-up-functionality)
            pullUpEl = document.createElement('div');
            pullUpEl.className = 'pullUp';
            pullUpEl.innerHTML = '<span class="pullUpIcon"></span><span class="pullUpLabel">Pull up to load more...</span>';
            //scrollerObj.appendChild(pullUpEl);
        }

        me.myScroll = new IScroll(wrapperObj, iScrollConfig);

        me.myScroll.on('refresh', function() {
            if((pullDownEl) && (pullDownEl.className.match('loading'))) {
                pullDownEl.querySelector('.pullDownLabel').innerHTML = 'Pull down to refresh...';
                if(this.y >= 0) {
                    // The pull-down-bar is fully visible:
                    // Hide it with a simple 250ms animation
                    hidePullDownEl(250, true);
                } else if(this.y > -pullDownOffset) {
                    // The pull-down-bar is PARTLY visible:
                    pullDownEl.style.marginTop = this.y + 'px';

                    // CSS-trick to force webkit to render/update any CSS-changes immediately: Access the offsetHeight property...
                    pullDownEl.offsetHeight;

                    var animTime = (250 * (pullDownOffset + this.y) / pullDownOffset);
                    this.scrollTo(0, 0, 0);   
                    setTimeout(function() { 
                        hidePullDownEl(animTime, true);
                    }, 0);

                } else {
                    hidePullDownEl(0, true);
                    this.scrollBy(0, pullDownOffset, 0);
                }
            }
            if((pullUpEl) && (pullUpEl.className.match('loading'))) {
                pullUpEl.className = 'pullUp';
                pullUpEl.querySelector('.pullUpLabel').innerHTML = 'Pull up to load more...';
            }
        });

        me.myScroll.on('scrollStart', function() {
            scrollStartPos = this.y; // Store the scroll starting point to be able to track movement in 'scroll' below
        });

        me.myScroll.on('scroll', function() {
            if(pullDownEl || pullUpEl) {
                if((scrollStartPos == 0) && (this.y == 0)) {
                    this.hasVerticalScroll = true;

                    // Set scrollStartPos to -1000 to be able to detect this state later...
                    scrollStartPos = -1000;
                } else if((scrollStartPos == -1000) &&
                    (((!pullUpEl) && (!pullDownEl.className.match('flip')) && (this.y < 0)) ||
                    ((!pullDownEl) && (!pullUpEl.className.match('flip')) && (this.y > 0)))) {
                    this.hasVerticalScroll = false;
                    scrollStartPos = 0;
                    this.scrollBy(0, -this.y, 0);   // Adjust scrolling position to undo this "invalid" movement
                }
            }

            if(pullDownEl) {
                if(this.y > pullDownOffset + pullThreshold && !pullDownEl.className.match('flip')) {
                    showPullDownElNow('flip');
                    this.scrollBy(0, -pullDownOffset, 0);   // Adjust scrolling position to match the change in pullDownEl's margin-top
                    pullDownEl.querySelector('.pullDownLabel').innerHTML = 'Release to refresh...';
                } else if(this.y < 0 && pullDownEl.className.match('flip')) { // User changes his mind...
                    hidePullDownEl(0, false);
                    this.scrollBy(0, pullDownOffset, 0);    // Adjust scrolling position to match the change in pullDownEl's margin-top
                    pullDownEl.querySelector('.pullDownLabel').innerHTML = 'Pull down to refresh...';
                }
            }
            if(pullUpEl) {
                if(this.y < (this.maxScrollY - pullThreshold) && !pullUpEl.className.match('flip')) {
                    pullUpEl.className = 'pullUp flip';
                    pullUpEl.querySelector('.pullUpLabel').innerHTML = 'Release to load more...';
                } else if(this.y > (this.maxScrollY + pullThreshold) && pullUpEl.className.match('flip')) {
                    pullUpEl.className = 'pullUp';
                    pullUpEl.querySelector('.pullUpLabel').innerHTML = 'Pull up to load more...';
                }
            }
        });

        me.myScroll.on('scrollEnd', function() {
            if((pullDownEl) && (pullDownEl.className.match('flip'))) {
                showPullDownElNow('loading');
                pullDownEl.querySelector('.pullDownLabel').innerHTML = 'Loading...';
                pullDownActionHandler(this);    // Execute custom function (ajax call?)
            }
            if((pullUpEl) && (pullUpEl.className.match('flip'))) {
                pullUpEl.className = 'pullUp loading';
                pullUpEl.querySelector('.pullUpLabel').innerHTML = 'Loading...';
                pullUpActionHandler(this);  // Execute custom function (ajax call?)
            }
            if(scrollStartPos == -1000) {
                this.hasVerticalScroll = this.options.scrollY && this.maxScrollY < 0;
            }
        });

        me.myScroll.refresh();
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        init();
    }, false);
};


var scroller1 = new IScrollPullUpDown('wrapper', {
    probeType: 2,
    bounceTime: 250,
    bounceEasing: 'quadratic',
    mouseWheel: false,
    scrollbars: true,
    fadeScrollbars: true,
    interactiveScrollbars: false,
    click: true,
    tap: true
}, pullDownAction, pullUpAction);

function blockTouchMove(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}

document.addEventListener('touchmove', blockTouchMove, false);
```

From this point Lets find the real problem.

P.S: Events for pull to refresh are working OK.

Comment: So first of all the whole code needs to be refactored, and organized. No Offence but this is a big mess. - agreed. I didn't write it, but my intention is to adapt it from the place it is from, and then clean it up after, but I can't even get it to work in it's original form

Comment: Also, I used the jQuery version nearest to the version I was using in my project.

Comment: The project is quite old and I'm trying to resurrect it

Comment: I tried to make two changes to the JSFiddle, and make a JSFiddle with code more similar to what I have live. https://jsfiddle.net/6ymesooL/7/ is the change I made (switched to jQuery 1.9.x) and here is closer to live: https://jsfiddle.net/qr6o5deq/6/

Comment: There's some material difference between the two, as one is not working.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander Hi andrew, which fiddle should I test exactly ?

Comment: Preferably the second one, that's closer to my current implementation, and even with your fixes isn't working

Comment: If you navigate to the JSFiddle in iOS you can't scroll.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander Tested on Mac iOS simulator and is working fine:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByMguvK1j1iFeTJBOU1aS1hCQUU

Comment: Seems to work for me, let me check the changes when compiled into an actual app. One moment.

Comment: What precisely did you change?

Comment: @AndrewAlexander you always forget to call the init function inside your constructor. Also your css was not correct as the parent should have smaller height than content or else it will not scroll.

Comment: Ok, so I guess I'll just diff the changes you made. And init() should call based on this:  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        init()
    }, false); - as I've said REPEATEDLY, I am trying to parse out what is going wrong from a sample of demo code I got from here: https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/issues/378 - I didn't write this.

Comment: @Andrew Alexander Let me know if I can provide further help. Please vote up for this if you find it helpful. Thanks :)

Comment: Ok. I'm playing around with it inside my mobile app, and it seems like it is getting closer to working, but not quite. Let me figure out what's wrong real quick

Comment: When I'm doing it as part of a mobile app, it only lets me scroll a limited distance, and only starts to let me scroll after I've refreshed once. I've been trying to get this fixed for a month. I'm just about ready to abandon iScroll and write this functionality myself, because this is incredibly, insanely frustrating.

Comment: Can you add me to mobile source code repo. Wanna have a look.

Comment: I've made a bunch of changes and am now using an entirely different library now, but sure. No matter what I try, I can't manage to get a scrolling div that lets me pull up and add to it. I've tried 3 libraries this week alone and all have similar problems. I don't know what I'm not understanding, but I'm not understanding something. This is literally the most impossible thing I've encountered in the entire time I've programmed and I don't feel it can be this hard. This is a common use case!

Comment: Ultimately I just switched to https://github.com/BoxFactura/pulltorefresh.js and that seems to have fixed my problem. 3 other libraries didn't.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander if it fails with 3 libs then there must be something wrong with structure, can you add me somewhere where I can have a look on source code ?

Comment: I added you on the repo, but a fourth library worked, so I'm going with that. I'll award you the points because you put in the most work and came up with a solution that sorta worked.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander Thank You, but I am still interested in investegating the issue with you, because we learn a lot from solving problems. Have you added justgeek to your repo ?

Comment: I did, but I have completely changed the codebase. You'll have to go about 10-15 commits back to get back to the old code. I cleaned it all up after fixing this issue

Comment: @AndrewAlexander so should I go back, or current code is working OK, in other words, If I manage to fix old code will you still need it?

Comment: I don't need it, I have the functionality I need at this point. This was the last major bug and I just couldn't solve it, so now the project is just about completed, with only little bits of functionality here or there to fix/add. Thank you!

Comment: @AndrewAlexander Ok, anytime. Also feel free to ask for help if you need a hand with this project. I see you are using cordova + phonegap, which is quite old. Ever Tried Ionic ?

Comment: I haven't. I started the project back in either late 2014 or early 2015 and never had the time to complete it, which is why I'm using older technologies. I'll take a look at Ionic.

Comment: I have used the same code for my mobile app, but it's not scrolling the first time. Any idea about the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are having issues on Android devices, then disable the passive mode of the event listener:

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', blockTouchMove, { passive: false });
```

---

From [MDN - Improve scrolling performance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Improving_scrolling_performance_with_passive_listeners):

> Starting in Chrome 56 (desktop, Chrome for Android, and Android
>   webview) the default value for touchstart and touchmove is true and
>   calls to preventDefault() are not permitted. To override this
>   behavior, you set the passive option to false.

Comment: Will this apply to PhoneGap? I believe that uses Webkit for mobile, but not specifically Chrome. Regardless, I'll test it.

Comment: On Android it uses the Android webview `android.webkit.WebView`.

Comment: I'm specifically seeing this issue on iOS.

Comment: Even with this change, behavior is still occurring. You can see it on the JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/qr6o5deq/11/

Comment: Yeah... I didn't think it would solve your issues. Keep it in mind though. Might come handy later on.

Comment: ProllyGeek has gotten me closer than anyone else so far and pretty much convinced me it is a style issue. Now it's just a matter of debugging it.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that is is being caused by your resizing, a little css will solve for you:

```
#messages-wrapper {
   padding-bottom:10vh;
}
```